# Where is Production.ps1 script in Sitecore docker images?

Tags: powershell, docker

This document https://www.sitecore.com/knowledge-center/getting-started/docker-entrypoints
describes two PowerShell scripts used as `ETRYPOINT`, named `Production.ps1` and `Development.ps1`.
They should be present in the containers based on the `Sitecore 10 Docker` CD image. While `Development.ps1` exists after the image build process, the first file is missing from the indicated folder: `C:\tools\entrypoints\iis`.

I have verified that the images are "**production ready**", and they are. I contacted Sitecore but they didn't answer me. Some idea?

Answer (score 2):

In short: That article is a bit outdated and is not applicable to recent 10.x containerised solutions.  The “production entrypoint” is now defined in each role’s base image and made publicly available via the Sitecore Container Registry. These entry points are the default unless specifically overwritten.  This is not necessarily *Production.ps1*, but executes the appropriate commands to run that role (similar to what is outlined in that article).  Hence you won’t find *Production.ps1* in those images, nor should it be required to spin up the containers.

Development.ps1 is present as your image build will be copying in the Sitecore docker tool assets.  Around the time v10 was released the Sitecore docker tool assets (https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-tools) were moved to their own image hosted in the Sitecore Container Registry (scr.sitecore.com/tools/) and the “production entry points” were baked into the base role images that Sitecore began providing in the SCR.  The tools assets became focussed on developer experience, while the default base images focussed on production readiness.

Prior to this (i.e. <= v9.3), all images had to be built from scratch (ie. base images are not provided in the SCR) and thus the sitecore-assets (including the tools) were included in the version specific build folders of the docker-images repo (e.g. https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-images/tree/master/build/windows/9.3.0/sitecore-assets/tools/entrypoints/iis) which gives a starting point to build these images.  Here you can see the Production.ps1 script.

Of course, you can still override any of the entry points in your dockerfile or docker-compose if required, the production.ps1 is just no longer part of the tools assets.